# Excel using INDEX to get row from named range causes formula error

Tags: excel, vba, row, named-ranges

I have a very simple formula to get the sum of values in a row:

```
=SUM(K5:P5)
```

However, K5 to P5 is the first row in a named range, and I would prefer to reference the named range, so I change it to:

```
=SUM(INDEX(S2ScoresTotUnitQ1,Row("A1"),0))
```

But I get a "we found a problem with this formula error". How do I reference individual rows of my named range without getting an error?

Comment: Probably like this `=SUM(S2ScoresTotUnitQ1)`?

Comment: Won't that sum all scores in the named range? My named range has multiple rows, and I only want to sum one row.

Comment: Then like this `=SUM(INDEX(S2ScoresTotUnitQ1;1;))`

Comment: @user3925803 See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove double quote from `A1` referrence. Means `Row("A1")` will be `Row(A1)`. So, formula will be as following

```
=SUM(INDEX(S2ScoresTotUnitQ1,ROW(A1),0))
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes I wanted to use ROW() so that it would be a relative reference when I copy and paste.

Comment: @Ralph He did a big mistake with `Row(A1)` and you are saying it is not a important part. It was only error of his formula. Otherwise all were okay.

Comment: @harun24hr My point is that `1` = `Row(A1)` = `12/12` = `25 -12 / 6 + 17 - 30 * 4 - 20/5 + COLUMN(Z1)+ROW(A25)+VALUE("34")`. Why over complicate the formula and use some function when you can simply use `1` instead? `=SUM(INDEX(S2ScoresTotUnitQ1,1,0))`

Answer (score 0):

The column in the `Index` formula is an optional argument, you do not have to pass it, if you do not wish. Thus, something like this should work:

`=SUM(INDEX(S2ScoresTotUnitQ1;1;))`

Whenever the formula has these `[` and `]` like here, it is optional argument:
[image]

Comment: Welcome, @Ralph :)